# Flexslider navigation position

Tags: jquery, navigation, flexslider

Is there any option how to get flexslider navigation (it is `directionNav: true`) to specific `<div>` ? Now, there is no option how to control, where the navigation appears. It appears always inside

```
<div class="flexslider">
```

I want to make it outside the

```
<div class="flexslider">
```

Comment: I think, that you dont need a code. But anyway: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7e444/)

Comment: By looking at the source code - why don't you move the ul elements outside the div in your html body?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such option in the plugin. 
But there is way for what you are trying to achieve.
Using css/javascript set the `display:none` of `.flex-prev` and `.flex-next` . Now add your custom navigation handler wherever you want.
Let's say you have `.next` and `.prev` as your custom handlers.
now using jquery/javascript you can bind click events to them which in turn will trigger click events to the actual `.flex-prev` and `.flex-next` to accomplish what you want to do. Your jsfiddle doesn't work, it would have been better if there was a working jsfiddle from your side.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/85/

Javascript:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
});
$(document).on('click','.next',function(){
    $('.flex-direction-nav .flex-next:first').trigger('click');
    return false;
});
$(document).on('click','.prev',function(){
    $('.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:first').trigger('click');
    return false;
});
```